# How can I get SWT browser history? What could be the different ways to get the native browser history?

Tags: java, browser, swt

I am intercepting the SWT browser events in my code. Now I want to access a previously opened URL and modify it by appending some other parameters into it. I am stuck on how to fetch SWT browser history to get the URL list. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SWT browser does not maintain a history. If you want this you need to use `Browser.addLocationListener` to add a `LocationListener` to the browser.

The `LocationListener` looks like:

```
private class LocationChange implements LocationListener
{    
  @Override
  public void changing(final LocationEvent event)
  {
    // You can use 'event.doit = false' to stop the change here
  }

  @Override
  public void changed(final LocationEvent event)
  {
    // Record the change
  }
}
```

Comment: I am intercepting the urls using the changing method. Here I want to get a url which I browsed say 5 mins back and append some parameters into that url. So here I am looking to get the browser history. please help

Comment: I am saying you need to add code to the `changed` method to maintain that history yourself using a list of something like that.